# get only records which have similar values in column A and different values in column B

Tags: sql, postgresql

My dataset has 2 tables:

1. animals with animal_id and animal_type
2. owners with animal_id and owner_name

I want to get records only for those animals (+ their owners name) which owners have a CAT and another different pet.

Here is my schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `animals` (
  `animal_id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `animal_type` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`animal_id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `animals` (`animal_id`, `animal_type`) VALUES
  ('1', 'cat'),
  ('2', 'dog'),
  ('3', 'cat'),
  ('4', 'cat'),
  ('5', 'dog'),
  ('6', 'dog'),
  ('7', 'cat'),
  ('8', 'dog'),
  ('9', 'cat'),
  ('10', 'hamster');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `owners` (
  `animal_id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `owner_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`animal_id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `owners` (`animal_id`, `owner_name`) VALUES
  ('1', 'CatOwner'),
  ('2', 'DogOwner'),
  ('3', 'CatsOwner'),
  ('4', 'CatsOwner'),
  ('5', 'DogsOwner'),
  ('6', 'DogsOwner'),
  ('7', 'CatDogOwner'),
  ('8', 'CatDogOwner'),
  ('9', 'CatHamsterOwner'),
  ('10', 'CatHamsterOwner');
```

I can filter and show only records for owners which have more then one pet:

```
SELECT *
FROM animals AS a
JOIN owners AS o
ON a.animal_id = o.animal_id 
WHERE o.owner_name IN (SELECT o.owner_name
                       FROM animals AS a
                       JOIN owners AS o
                       ON a.animal_id = o.animal_id 
                       GROUP BY o.owner_name HAVING COUNT(o.owner_name) > 1)
```

Please tell me how can I make it this way:

[image]

Comment: The DDL shown is invalid for Postgres. Looks like you are actually using MySQL

Comment: HAVING, case expressions.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it's just a sample using the sqlfiddle.com/ , my tables more columns

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest window functions:

```
SELECT ao.*
FROM (SELECT a.*, o.owner_name,
             SUM(CASE WHEN a.animal_type = 'cat' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY o.owner_name) as num_cats,
             COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY o.owner_name) as num_animals
      FROM owners o JOIN
           animals a
           ON a.animal_id = o.animal_id 
     ) ao
WHERE num_cats > 0 AND num_animals >= 2;
```

Note:  I'm not clear if the condition is for more than one animal or an animal that is not a cat.  If the latter, then use:

```
SELECT ao.*
FROM (SELECT a.*, o.owner_name,
             SUM(CASE WHEN a.animal_type = 'cat' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY o.owner_name) as num_cats,
             COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY o.owner_name) as num_animals
      FROM owners o JOIN
           animals a
           ON a.animal_id = o.animal_id 
     ) ao
WHERE num_cats > 0 AND num_animals <> num_cats;
```

Comment: I need those owners which have a cat + smth other which is not a cat

Comment: @Kosh . . . This answer covers that interpretation as well.